# Cómo solucionar error list out of range

Tags: python, diccionarios

Soy nueva en todo esto de Python. Al ejecutar este código me aparece el siguiente error:  `line 11, in <module> diccionario[termino[0]]=termino[1]IndexError: list index out of range`
Ya cambié los valores dentro de los `[]` pero no pasó nada, si alguien me puede ayudar sería magnífico.

**Código:**

```
introducir el código aquí

nombre_archivo = "Glosario.txt"
archivo = open(nombre_archivo,"r")

texto = archivo.read()
archivo.close()
lineas = texto.splitlines()
terminos = texto.split(":")
diccionario={}
for linea in lineas:
termino = linea.split(":")
diccionario[termino[0]]=termino[1]

buscar = input("Indique el termino a buscar en el diccionario: ")
encontrado = diccionario.get(buscar)
if encontrado:
   print(buscar+":"+" "+encontrado)
else:
     print("Termino no existe ene l glosario")
ingresar_termino = input("Desea ingresar este termino(s/n):")
if (ingresar_termino=='s'):
    archivo = open(nombre_archivo,"a")
    nuevo_termino = input("Indique la descripción del termino "+buscar+":")
    archivo.write("\n"+buscar+":"+nuevo_termino)
    archivo.close()
```

Comment: Haz un `print(termino)` después del `split()` y fijate que estas leyendo.

Comment: cambié termino[0] por i y ya ejecuto bien. Gracias Candid Moe